# U-substitution $\int \left (1+e^{at} \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-at}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I solve this integral only with u-substitution? Is this possible?

$$\int \left (1+e^{at} \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-at}dt$$

I know how to evaluate this integral, my question is how can I obtain this primitive without partial fractions, just substitution. Thank you.

Comment: partial fractions won't get you anywhere.  So how did you evaluate the integral?

Comment: Hint: This equals the [Chebyshev Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegral.html) after $x=-e^{at}$.

Comment: @amWhy I just did the substitution 1 + exp (at) = u and finished with partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \left(e^{a t}+1\right)^{3/2} e^{-a t} \, dt$$
substitute $ e^{-a t} =u$ so that $-ae^{-a t} dt=du\rightarrow dt=\dfrac{du}{-au}$

The integral becomes
$$-\frac{1}{a}\int \left(\frac{1}{u}+1\right)^{3/2}  \, du$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
 u = e^{at}, \qquad du = a e^{at} dt
$$
Therefore
$$
  dt = \frac{1}{a u} du
$$

---

$$
\int \left( 1 + e^{at} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} e^{-at} dt 
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\int \frac{\left( 1 + e^{at} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{a u^{2}} du
$$